# How to test a button that calls System.exit() with Espresso

Tags: java, android, junit4, android-espresso, ui-testing

Im new to Espresso. I was writing tests to check the menu options. I have a menu option called EXIT. This option when pressed calls System.exit() and the application quits. I was wondering how to test this with Espresso.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The simplest thing would be to get rid of that menu option. Using `System.exit()` is an anti-pattern in Android development.

Comment: See also [this video on the exit button anti-pattern](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=631T7B8HOv4)